# How to compare production datetime to the reference table?

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have Two tables one is "Reference" Table another one is "Production" Table.If i get a production report, "Production" table should refer the "Reference" Table and compare it's EntryDateTime.
[image]

[image]

I want result should be like this, If I have provided Barcode is "B1" then

[image]

If Barcode is "B2"

[image]

Help me out to get this result.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables

```
select prod.date1, prod.station, prod.barcode, ref.name, ref.[desc], prod.r1value, prod.r2value from reference ref  join production prod 
on ref.station = prod.station where prod.Barcode = 'B1'  and  ref.name <> 'VTL3'
select prod.date1, prod.station, prod.barcode, ref.name, ref.[desc], prod.r1value, prod.r2value from reference ref  join production prod 
on ref.station = prod.station  where prod.Barcode = 'B2' and ref.name <> 'VTL1'
```

or filter on join

```
select prod.date1, prod.station, prod.barcode, ref.name, ref.[desc], prod.r1value, prod.r2value from reference ref  join production prod 
on ref.station = prod.station and ref.name <> 'VTL3' where prod.Barcode = 'B1'

select prod.date1, prod.station, prod.barcode, ref.name, ref.[desc], prod.r1value, prod.r2value from reference ref  join production prod 
on ref.station = prod.station and ref.name <> 'VTL1' where prod.Barcode = 'B2'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually -- select * from production where barcode ='B1' and joins No need to mention reference name because there are so many reference names.so we have to use only Barcode no other stuffs.

Comment: Ah... In that case you will need to add barcode to reference table as well.

Comment: Reference table does not have barcode, it says what are the columns required from production table.In this case production table have barcode it is transaction table.